# Menu Submenu only with CSS

Tags: html, css, focus

I want to create menu submenu concept only using css. It its not working as expected. Expected Output A-> A1 -> A1-1 , same for other elements too. This is what I tried so far. now 1 level submenu is working.

I tried to apply same as [this link](https://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/133/index.html)

```css
.list_item {
  padding: 5px;
}
.blade {
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: #ddd;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.blade .blade {
  display: none;
  left: 190px;
}
.list_item a:active + div.blade,
.list_item a:focus + div.blade,
.list_item a:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="blade ng-scope">


  <div class="list_item ng-scope">
    <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">A</a>

    <div class="blade ng-scope">


      <div class="list_item ng-scope">
        <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">A1</a>

        <div class="blade ng-scope">


          <div class="list_item ng-scope">
            <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">A1-1</a>

            <div class="blade ng-scope">


              <div class="list_item ng-scope">
                <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">A1-1 - 1</a>
              </div>

              <div class="list_item ng-scope">
                <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">A1-1 - 2</a>
              </div>

              <div class="list_item ng-scope">
                <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">A1-1 - 3</a>
              </div>

              <div class="list_item ng-scope">
                <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">A1-1 - 4</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="list_item ng-scope">
        <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">A2</a>

        <div class="blade ng-scope">


          <div class="list_item ng-scope">
            <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">A2-1</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="list_item ng-scope">
        <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">A3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="list_item ng-scope">
    <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">B</a>

    <div class="blade ng-scope">


      <div class="list_item ng-scope">
        <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">B1</a>
      </div>

      <div class="list_item ng-scope">
        <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">B2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="list_item ng-scope">
    <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">C</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use ul>li?

Comment: @guvenckardas In my case, I can't use ul. It should be div and there may another elements inside div

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4hhgjaus/ you can check this one too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its hard to make it only with css, because its not supporting events like click etc. , your problem is, that you loose `:focus` status, so you need to keep your `.blade` div alive another way, my idea is to use `:hover` on div itself, with good html organisation it would work pretty good:
**NOTE** this wont work in some mobile phones, because they dont support `:hover` pseudo class

```css
.list_item {
  padding: 5px;
}
.blade {
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background: #ddd;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.blade .blade {
  display: none;
  left: 190px;
}
.list_item div.blade:hover,
.list_item a:active + div.blade,
.list_item a:focus + div.blade,
.list_item a:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="blade ng-scope">


  <div class="list_item ng-scope">
    <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">A</a>

    <div class="blade ng-scope">


      <div class="list_item ng-scope">
        <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">A1</a>

        <div class="blade ng-scope">


          <div class="list_item ng-scope">
            <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">A1-1</a>

            <div class="blade ng-scope">


              <div class="list_item ng-scope">
                <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">A1-1 - 1</a>
              </div>

              <div class="list_item ng-scope">
                <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">A1-1 - 2</a>
              </div>

              <div class="list_item ng-scope">
                <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">A1-1 - 3</a>
              </div>

              <div class="list_item ng-scope">
                <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">A1-1 - 4</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="list_item ng-scope">
        <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">A2</a>

        <div class="blade ng-scope">


          <div class="list_item ng-scope">
            <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">A2-1</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="list_item ng-scope">
        <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">A3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="list_item ng-scope">
    <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">B</a>

    <div class="blade ng-scope">


      <div class="list_item ng-scope">
        <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">B1</a>
      </div>

      <div class="list_item ng-scope">
        <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">B2</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="list_item ng-scope">
    <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">C</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Working hover version [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4hhgjaus/)

```
   .list_item {
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .blade {
        height: 400px;
        width: 200px;
        border: 1px solid;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        background: #ddd;
        z-index: 1000;
    }
    .blade .blade {
        display: none;
        left: 190px;
    }


    .list_item:hover{
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .list_item:hover  > div.blade {
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
    }
```

html:

```
<div class="blade ng-scope">


    <div class="list_item ng-scope">
        <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">A</a>

        <div class="blade ng-scope">


            <div class="list_item ng-scope">
                <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">A1</a>

                <div class="blade ng-scope">


                    <div class="list_item ng-scope">
                        <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">A1-1</a>

                        <div class="blade ng-scope">


                            <div class="list_item ng-scope">
                                <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">A1-1 - 1</a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="list_item ng-scope">
                                <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">A1-1 - 2</a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="list_item ng-scope">
                                <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">A1-1 - 3</a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="list_item ng-scope">
                                <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">A1-1 - 4</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="list_item ng-scope">
                <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">A2</a>

                <div class="blade ng-scope">


                    <div class="list_item ng-scope">
                        <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">A2-1</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="list_item ng-scope">
                <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">A3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="list_item ng-scope">
        <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">B</a>

        <div class="blade ng-scope">


            <div class="list_item ng-scope">
                <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">B1</a>
            </div>

            <div class="list_item ng-scope">
                <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">B2</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="list_item ng-scope">
        <a class="item_a ng-binding" tabindex="0">C</a>
    </div>
</div>
```